# How to put in array the children of the children

Tags: java, aem

```
private static JSONArray getListOfChildPagesAsJSON(Page page) {
    JSONArray pagesArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        Iterator<Page> childPages = page.listChildren();
        while (childPages.hasNext()) {
            Page childPage = childPages.next();
            JSONObject pageObject = new JSONObject();
            pageObject.put(childPage.getTitle(), childPage.getPath());
            pagesArray.put(pageObject);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return pagesArray;
}
```

So that not only the children of the transferred page put into array, but also the children of the children.

Comment: Looks like you work with AEM or Magnolia.

Comment: @Reporter with aem

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical case for recursion, like reading directoy tree on filesystem. My suggestion is as follows:

First step: Change the scope of variable `JSONArray pagesArray = new JSONArray();` from function to class scope.

```
public MyClass {
  private JSONArray pagesArray = new JSONArray();
  ...
}
```

Step two: Change return value to `void` and the modifier of your function by removing `static`.

```
private void getListOfChildPagesAsJSON(Page page) { }
```

Step three add the missing recusion to your its body.

```
//JSONArray pagesArray = new JSONArray();
try {
    Iterator<Page> childPages = page.listChildren();
    while (childPages.hasNext()) {
        Page childPage = childPages.next();
        JSONObject pageObject = new JSONObject();
        pageObject.put(childPage.getTitle(), childPage.getPath());
        
        //Add the created object to your array which is class variable 
        this.pagesArray.put(pageObject);
        
        //--Check for each single page for child pages again
        Iterator<Page> childPagesOfChildpage = childPage.listChildren();
        while (childPagesOfChildpage.hasNext()) {
            getListOfChildPagesAsJSON(childPagesOfChildpage.next());
        }
        //--
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Note: The check `childPage.hasChild()` does not work here, because the node `jcr:content` is a valid child of passed page.